# `bundle exec` doesn't work, says "`mri_22` is not a valid platform"

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to run a command using `bundle exec` in my Ruby project. Whenever I run it, though, I get an error message that looks like:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
`mri_22` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18,
:ruby_19, :ruby_20, :ruby_21, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :mri_20, :mri_21, :rbx,
:jruby, :jruby_18, :jruby_19, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19, :mingw_20,
:mingw_21, :x64_mingw, :x64_mingw_20, :x64_mingw_21]
```

How do I get `bundle` to work?

Comment: [I already know the answer to this question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) I'm posting it to make the answer easier to find by future Googlers and askers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of bundler that you're running is out of date. Install the newest `bundle` gem by running

```
gem update bundler
```

Source: https://github.com/codeforamerica/congress/issues/10